# Oracle double count case

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

I have the following sql statement:

```
     COUNT(CASE 
          WHEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) IS NULL THEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(AA.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2 THEN 1
          ELSE CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2 THEN 1 
     END) AS Calculatedsum
```

Where `CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD)` is a function that returns a sum (in seconds)

However i am getting the error

> Missing keyword

What am i doing wrong ? and is it even possible to count this way?

**UPDATE**

i have also tried the following:

```
 CASE WHEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(AA.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2
 THEN 1 END 
ELSIF CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) /60 / 60 <2 THEN 1 END IF) AS Calculatedsum
```

The problem is if the result of the calculation is null then it should calculate the sum in another way and check if thats less than 2 then count it as +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing another `WHEN` (you've got two `THEN`s in a row). This

```
WHEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) IS NULL -- MISSING VALUE
THEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(AA.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2 THEN 1
-- ^-- Wrong keyword
```

should be

```
COUNT(CASE
  WHEN CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) IS NULL THEN
    CASE
    WHEN (CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(AA.THIS_DATE_OPENING, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2)
      OR (CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 < 2) THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
  ELSE 0
END) AS Calculatedsum
```

Comment: The problem lies with the fact that if the function returns null it should try the function but with two new parameters and it should then count them else run the else case

In short i dont want to get null but instead avoid null

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Take a look at the edit - you need a nested `CASE`.

Comment: the two else cases that are 0 shouldnt one of them be CALCULATE_CALLBACK_DURATION(CREATED, LAST_UPD) /60 /60 ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I think you can combine the two conditions with an `OR`, because in both cases you return `1`.